# c++ program runs correctly, but the same python program not

Tags: python, c++

My task is:
C2[9]. Given natural number N. Remove from the number the third digit (from left). Example #1. N = 1256; answer: 126. Example #2. N = 432; answer: 43. Example #3. N = 98; answer: 98.

I wrote the code in c++ and it works according to the task. I tried the same task in python but there the output is wrong...

Here is the code in python:

```
x = 10292989
xx = x

if x <= 99:
    print(x)
else:
    d=1
    while x > 999:
        x//10
        d**10
    
    x//10
    fin = x * d + xx % d
    print(fin)
```

Here is the code in c++:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int c2(int);

int main(){
int x = 10292989;

cout<<c2(x)<<endl;
}

int c2(int x){
    int d=1;
    int xx = x;
    int fin;
    if(x <= 99){
        return x;
    }
    else{
        while(x > 999){
            x /= 10;
            d *= 10;
        }

        x/=10;

        return fin = x * d + xx % d;
    }
}
```

Comment: `x//10` doesn't change `x`. It needs to be `x = x//10` or `x //= 10`

Comment: how do i change x then

Comment: The same way you change any other variable: assign something to it.

Comment: The same way that you changed x to `10292989` at the beginning of the program, or the way that you change `fin` near the end.

Comment: ok now it's terminating, but the output is still wrong... I wrote the same code in c++ and there it works...

Comment: `d**10` has the same problem.

Comment: C requires you to assign to the variable just like Python does. So if you know C, I don't know why you would be having a problem with this.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to translate code. Translation is hard. Often harder than writing code from scratch. In order to successfully translate code you need to understand both languages deeply enough to understand the behaviour of the code in the source language and reimplement it in the other language. This is similar to translating a spoken language. If you do not understand how to produce the same subtext and context in both languages at best you wind up with [All Your Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us)-style nonsense.

Comment: I found the problem, now it works, thanks for all the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `x//10` changes the variable only in memory, not overwrites the variable, so try (`x = x//10`):

```
x = 10292989
xx = x

if x <= 99:
    print(x)
else:
    d=1
    while x > 999:
        x = x//10
        d = d**10
    
    x = x//10
    fin = x * d + xx % d
    print(fin)
```

Comment: `d**10` should be `d = d**10`

Comment: @Barmar thanks for this

Comment: thanks for the help, sadly its still not working